# Selecting (i.e., as the region) the current match in incremental search

Tags: search, region, isearch, selection

When searching for a string with `C-s`, I want to be able to hit some key to exit search mode *but still maintain the selection of the match.* That way I can immediately start typing and replace the last match.

For example, say I have the following document:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

If I search for "lazy", emacs will select that word like so (square brackets are selection, pipe is cursor):

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the [lazy|] dog.
```

Now, if I press <kbd>return</kbd>, emacs will maintain my cursor position, but it will deselect "lazy":

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy| dog.
```

Instead of this, I want a shortcut that will exit search mode but maintain the current match selection, like in the second state above.

Comment: Isn't `M-x query-replace` what you're looking for?

Comment: @Nsukami_ I do not always know what I want my query to be or even what I want to replace it with before I search. It's much easier to just hit `C-s` and type what I think I want to search for, then change the query w/ backspace to zero in on the thing I want to change. Then I play around with what exactly I want to replace it with. `M-%` is too "formal."

Comment: The solution comes in handy for me, like when I search for a word to kill it and then yank it to a different place. `query-replace` doesn’t solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
(defun isearch-exit-mark-match ()
  "Exit isearch and mark the current match."
  (interactive)
  (isearch-exit)
  (push-mark isearch-other-end)
  (activate-mark))

(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "<C-return>") #'isearch-exit-mark-match)
```

This binds a different key (C-return) to exit the current isearch and also leave the last match selected. This will work with `isearch-forward-regexp` as well, which is handy.

Comment: I get "Symbol's function definition is void: bind-key." Where is `bind-key` coming from?

Comment: Sorry, `bind-key` comes from another library. I've changed the answer to use the built-in `define-key` function instead.

Answer (score 4):

Library [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) lets you [do that easily](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus#isearchp-set-region-flag), and even toggle it on/off on the fly.

- Non-nil option **`isearchp-set-region-flag`** automatically sets the region (selection) around the last search target when you quit isearch.
- Command `isearchp-toggle-set-region`, bound to **`M-s M-SPC`** during isearch toggles option `isearchp-set-region-flag`.
- Command **`set-region-around-search-target`** manually sets the region around the last search target. (So even if the option is not set, so you don't get automatic selection, you can do it manually.)

---

Library [Replace+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReplacePlus) lets you [do the same thing](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReplacePlus#set-region-around-search-target) for `query-replace` etc.  It puts the region around (i.e., selects) the last replacement occurrence. It uses the same option, `isearchp-set-region-flag`, to control this, and command `set-region-around-search-target` has the same effect.