# Make region transient in elisp function

Tags: region, isearch, mark, shift-selection, transient-mark-mode

I'm trying to write a function that exits isearch leaving the current match selected "transiently", so that the mark is deactivated by any unshifted movement command.

I've tried to modify this function,

```
(defun isearch-exit-mark-match ()
  "Exit isearch and mark the current match."
  (interactive)
  (isearch-exit)
  (push-mark isearch-other-end)
  (activate-mark))
```

[[source](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31320/selecting-i-e-as-the-region-the-current-match-in-incremental-search)] which does select the matching string, but doesn't do so with a transient mark. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the implementation of the function [`handle-shift-selection`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/f18af6cd5cb7dbbf7420ec2d3efed4e202c4f0dd/lisp/simple.el#L5787), you can try something like this

```
(defun isearch-exit-mark-match ()
  "Exit isearch and mark the current match."
  (interactive)
  (isearch-exit)
  (setq-local transient-mark-mode
              (cons 'only transient-mark-mode))
  (push-mark isearch-other-end nil t))

(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "<C-return>") #'isearch-exit-mark-match)
```